# Can I export a container with data and everything to spawn a complete copy on another computer?

Tags: docker

I am looking into Docker and trying to wrap my head around it, so I might have misunderstood the concept.

I have installed the [sebp/elk](https://hub.docker.com/r/sebp/elk/) (ElasticSearch-Logstash-Kibana) and have a working container running. I have setup some indices and posted some data to logstash, which is stored with the container. If I restart the container everything works as expected. Now I am interested in exporting the container as it is, to launch on another computer with the configurations and data I have setup.

So I have tried `export` the container and `import` it as a new image and `run` the container from the new image. The container works, but it starts up as a new container without all the data, that I put into the original container.

I also tried to `commit` my changes to the image, then `save` the image and `load` it again and then `run` the container from the new image. That also works, but again without any data.

So when I `inspect` the original container, I can see that it has a mounted volume, so I figured that I should try to export the elasticsearch data to a .tar file and then import into the new container. But that didn't work either.

This is the mount inspection of the original container:

```
"Mounts": [
        {
            "Name": "fe17e920f9d17e177ac899b1617a8c51231c8a3b34007f463d082e5be2677412",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/fe17e920f9d17e177ac899b1617a8c51231c8a3b34007f463d082e5be2677412/_data",
            "Destination": "/var/lib/elasticsearch",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ]
```

Here is how I tried to export it:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from elk -v $(pwd):/volumes original/sebp/elk:exported tar cvf /volumes/elk-volume.tar /var/lib/elasticsearch
```

... and this is how I tried to import it:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from elk-imported -v $(pwd):/volumes original/sebp/elk:exported bash -c "cd /volumes && tar xvf /volumes/elk-volume.tar --strip 1"
```

Is it possible to export a Docker container to get an exact copy of it with data and everything or am I approaching this problem the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct, docker export command does not export the contents of volumes associated with the container, so you have to export the container than backup volume data.

Be sure you have elk-imported container already running before doing volume restore.

```
docker run -v /volumes --name elk-imported  original/sebp/elk:exported /bin/bash
docker run --rm --volumes-from elk-imported -v $(pwd):/volumes original/sebp/elk:exported bash -c "cd /volumes && tar xvf /volumes/elk-volume.tar --strip 1"
```